# Undefined reference to vtable (out of ideas)

Tags: c++, oop

I have gone through all I could find on net but seems like I am missing some very basic thing, having spent so much time on this problem isn't making things easier, so I will go ahead and ask for a help here, see if you can find what I am doing wrong.

Here is the code :

jControl.h

```
#ifndef _JCONTROL_H
#define _JCONTROL_H

namespace view
{


class jControl
{

public:


HWND hwnd;
HWND hParent;
HBITMAP hbitmap;
std::string text;
HFONT hFont;
COLORREF textColor;
COLORREF backgroundColor;
RECT updateRegion;
bool isUpdateRegion;

public:


jControl (  );

jControl ( HWND parent, HINSTANCE hInstance, WORD bitmap );

~jControl (  );

virtual void show (  );

virtual void hide (  );

virtual void disable (  );

virtual void enable (  );

virtual std::string getText (  );

virtual void setText ( std::string txt );

virtual void setUpdateRegion ( RECT rect );

virtual void setTextColor ( COLORREF crf );

virtual void setBackgroundColor ( COLORREF crf );

virtual void setFont ( HFONT font );

virtual bool setRange ( int range );

virtual bool setStep ( int step );

};

};

#endif
```

jControl.cpp

```
#include "jControl.h"

namespace view
{



jControl::jControl(  ){};


jControl::jControl ( HWND parent, HINSTANCE hInstance, WORD bitmap ) 
                    : hParent ( parent ), hbitmap ( NULL ), isUpdateRegion ( false ), textColor (  RGB ( 255, 255, 255 )  ), backgroundColor (  RGB ( 54, 54, 54 )  )
{

    hFont = ::CreateFont ( 18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "Myriad Pro" );

    if ( bitmap != 0 )  hbitmap = LoadBitmap (  hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE ( bitmap )  );

};


jControl::~jControl (  ) 
{ 

  if ( hbitmap )    DeleteObject ( hbitmap );

  if ( hFont )      DeleteObject ( hFont );

  if ( hwnd )       DestroyWindow ( hwnd ); 

};

void jControl::show(  ) {   ::ShowWindow( hwnd, SW_SHOW );  };

void jControl::hide(  ) {   ::ShowWindow( hwnd, SW_HIDE );  };

void jControl::disable (  ) {   EnableWindow ( hwnd, false );   };

void jControl::enable (  )  {   EnableWindow ( hwnd, true );    };

std::string jControl::getText (  )  {   return text;    };

void jControl::setText ( std::string txt )  {   text = txt;     InvalidateRect ( hwnd, NULL, true );    };

void jControl::setUpdateRegion ( RECT rect )    {   updateRegion = rect;    isUpdateRegion = true;  };

void jControl::setTextColor ( COLORREF crf )    {  textColor = crf;  };

void jControl::setBackgroundColor ( COLORREF crf )  {  backgroundColor = crf; ::InvalidateRect ( hwnd, NULL, true );  };

void jControl::setFont ( HFONT font )   {   hFont = font;   };

bool jControl::setRange ( int range )   {   return true;    };

bool jControl::setStep ( int step )     {   return true;    };

};
```

jProgressBar.h

```
#ifndef _JPROGRESSBAR_H
#define _JPROGRESSBAR_H




/**     * Parent class include      */
#ifndef _JCONTROL_H
   #include  "../jControl/jControl.h"
#endif


namespace view
{

class jProgressBar : public jControl
{


public:

jProgressBar ( std::string txt, int x, int y, int width, int height, HWND parent, HINSTANCE hInstance, WORD bitmap );

~jProgressBar (  );

std::string getText (  );

void setText ( std::string txt );

bool setRange ( int range );

bool setStep ( int step );


};

};

#endif
```

jProgressBar.cpp

```
#include "jProgressBar.h"

namespace view
{


jProgressBar::jProgressBar( std::string txt, int x, int y, int width, int height, HWND parent, HINSTANCE hInstance, WORD bitmap ) 
                  : jControl( parent, hInstance, bitmap )
{

    hwnd =  CreateWindowEx ( WS_EX_TOPMOST, PROGRESS_CLASS, txt.c_str(), WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CHILD, x, y, width, height, parent, 0, hInstance, 0 );

};

jProgressBar::~jProgressBar (  ){};

bool jProgressBar::setRange ( int range )
{ 

    if ( SendMessage (  hwnd, PBM_SETRANGE, 0, MAKELPARAM ( 0,  range )  ) != 0 )   return true;

    return false;

};

bool jProgressBar::setStep ( int step )
{ 

     if ( SendMessage (  hwnd, PBM_SETSTEP, ( WPARAM ) step, 0  ) != 0 )    return true;

    return false;

};


};
```

And here is the error :

```
[Linker error] jProgressBar/jProgressBar.cpp:14: undefined reference to `vtable for view::jProgressBar'
```

I get the error on Constructor and Destructor of JProgressBar.

Comment: Since you haven't provided your link command or OS, I can only guess, that you're trying to link object file from jProgressBar.cpp without object file from jControl.cpp

Comment: Probably not the cause of your problem, but you must declare jControl's destructor as virtual, otherwise jControl will not be destructed properly. As a rule, whenever you have a class that can be derived from, it should have a virtual destructor (possibly with an empty body).

Comment: When having virtual functions you should declare the destructor virtual too.

Comment: Irrelevant to the question but anyway... The reserved names in C/C++ are not that many, still you guys keep choosing them for no reason. Why on earth using `_JCONTROL_H`? Just because it's forbidden? Because makes you feel like you're a compiler implementer? Seems so kiddish. BTW the initial underscore was chosen because it's UGLY and it was thought no one would use it when writing programs...

Comment: @6502 "_JCONTROL_H" is not the actual variable(?) in the actual code, it's been edited to post here, it's there for the presentation purpose only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem may be in these lines:

```
std::string getText(  );
```

and

```
void setText( std::string txt );
```

in  jProgressBar.h

Please provide a definition for this function in Cpp or remove it from header, I think it should compile. The main reason is: you have overridden a virtual function in a child class with a declaration, but haven't given a definition for the method.
The compiler knows about the function, but the linker is not able to find the definition
For example:

```
class Base
{
    virtual void f() = 0;
}
class Derived : public Base
{
    void f();
}
```

Comment: Oh man, I am feeling so stupid. Sinc ethe problem started arising after I added "setRange" and "getRange" functions, I thought the problem was with them, and kept fiddling with them only. I knew the answer, but somehow wasn't able to look at if "setText" and "getText" are defined, in the first place these functions shouldn't be in jProgressBar.h :P